# Count maximum number of consecutive 1s per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Given a data frame of the following structure

```
df1  = pd.DataFrame( data = {'userid':[465,465,999,999,999,999],
                      'postedDate':[pd.to_datetime('2018-11-01'),pd.to_datetime('2018-11-20'),pd.to_datetime('2018-11-01'),pd.to_datetime('2018-11-08'),pd.to_datetime('2018-11-14'), pd.to_datetime('2018-11-29')],
                      'value':[1,1,1,1,1,1]}).set_index('postedDate')

df1 = df1.groupby('userid').resample('W').count().drop('userid', axis =1 )
df1
```

---

```
userid  postedDate  value
465     2018-11-04    1
        2018-11-11    0
        2018-11-18    0
        2018-11-25    1
999     2018-11-04    1
        2018-11-11    1
        2018-11-18    1
        2018-11-25    0
        2018-12-02    1
```

For each userid, I would like to get the maximum number of consecutive weeks with a value = 1. The result should be

```
userid  max_consecutive_wks
465        1
999        3
```

Given the size of the dataset, any solution using *for loops* won't work in Python, so I am looking for a **Pandas / Numpy** only vectorized approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shifting cumsum trick to get all groups of consecutive 1s, and then use `value_counts` to find the largest group.

```
u = df1['value'].eq(1)
v = u.ne(u.shift()).cumsum().where(u)

v.groupby(level=0).value_counts().max(level=0).reset_index(name='max_consec_wks')

   userid  max_consec_wks
0     465               1
1     999               3
```

The `where` call is required to ensure that only groups of 1s are considered (and not 0s).