# How to find a maximum length of consecutive increasing elements in time series data in pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series, data-analysis

I have a time series data with three columns (tilted as tool name, value, date)as below:

| Tool Name | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 52.14 | 1/1 |
| A | 51.5 | 1/7 |
| A | 52 | 1/10 |
| A | 52.9 | 2/1 |
| B | 53.1 | 1/5 |
| B | 51.7 | 1/10 |
| B | 51.9 | 1/21 |
| B | 52.4 | 1/22 |
| B | 53.0 | 2/1 |
| B | 51.5 | 2/15 |
| B | 50.5 | 2/16 |
| B | 52.5 | 2/17 |
| C | 50.4 | 1/22 |
| C | 51.0 | 2/1 |
| C | 52.0 | 2/15 |

I would like to find the maximum length of consecutive increasing values for each tool. For example we see that tool B's value has increased over time consecutively on 1/21, 1/22, 2/1 and 2/15 (length of increase = 4) and also for tool B we see another increase on 2/17 (length of increase = 1). there for the max number for tool B is 4. Note that we only count "**consecutive increases"**.

The final table will look like the below table:

| Tool | Max |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 1 |

I am wondering how can I write a code in pandas to give the desired result.
Thanks.

Comment: B does not increase on 2/15?

Comment: Also, C is increasing twice?

Comment: And A twice as well. Your entire desired result is off it seems, or I don't understand your logic completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think your desired output is off when evaluating your logic; A is increasing twice (row 3 and 4), B is increasing 3 times (not the last one you are referring to) and C is also increasing twice (last two rows). So, if you want an output that reflects that, you can use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tool Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'C', 13: 'C', 14: 'C'}, 'Value': {0: 52.14, 1: 51.5, 2: 52.0, 3: 52.9, 4: 53.1, 5: 51.7, 6: 51.9, 7: 52.4, 8: 53.0, 9: 51.5, 10: 50.5, 11: 52.5, 12: 50.4, 13: 51.0, 14: 52.0}, 'Date': {0: '1/1', 1: '1/7', 2: '1/10', 3: '2/1', 4: '1/5', 5: '1/10', 6: '1/21', 7: '1/22', 8: '2/1', 9: '2/15', 10: '2/16', 11: '2/17', 12: '1/22', 13: '2/1', 14: '2/15'}})
df = df.set_index(['Tool Name', 'Date'])
increased = df['Value'] > df.groupby('Tool Name')['Value'].shift()
intermediate = increased.ne(increased.shift()).cumsum().where(increased)
result = intermediate.groupby(level=0).value_counts().groupby(level=0).max().reset_index(name='consec_increases')
print(result)
#   Tool Name  consec_increases
# 0         A                 2
# 1         B                 3
# 2         C                 2
```

`increased` is a boolean series that indicates whether the value is an increase compared to the previous row `Value` within a `Tool Name` group.

`intermediate` does a cumsum() on that boolean series but only if it is consecutive increasing and only for where there was an increase in the first place.

`result` is a `groupby` on the cumsum values per group and counts the occurrences of each cumsum value per group. (Note; the cumsum values themselves are pointless).

It's a neat trick, inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207986/1557060).